# Warning assigning variables

Tags: magit, variables, byte-compilation, warning, defvar

I'm rebuilding my emacs configuration, and trying to compile without warnings. I'm using also cask. I have this case:

```
(require 'magit)

;; Enable a right limit of 70 chars for git logs
(add-hook 'magit-log-edit-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)

(provide 'my-magit)

(fullframe magit-status magit-mode-quit-window nil)
(setq magit-last-seen-setup-instructions "1.4.0")

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c g s") 'magit-status)

(require 'git-gutter)
(global-git-gutter-mode +1)
```

Compiling this, give this warning:

```
In toplevel form:
my-magit.el:10:7:Warning: assignment to free variable
    ‘magit-last-seen-setup-instructions’
```

I try and changing to

```
(defvar magit-last-seen-setup-instructions "1.4.0")
```

It works well, without warning, the difference with setq is that after that if another defvar is applied to this variable will ahve no effect, but could I apply it to the other variables like this or I will have issues for that. Another doubt is that I believe that this variable is defined in the package magit that is loaded previously. so I do not get why I get this warning.

Comment: "I believe that this variable is defined in the package magit" -- is it, though? If it's no longer defined, your assumption doesn't hold. (n.b. in current releases of magit, it is not defined.)

Answer (score 1):

You declare variables as global with `defvar` and optionally initialize them. When you use the `setq` the variable apparently hasn't been declared. It sounds like what your after is this construction

```
(defvar foo)
(setq foo "foo")
```

The first tells the compiler that `foo` is a global (dynamic) variable. The second sets it unconditionally.

Answer (score 1):

`magit-last-seen-setup-instructions` was not well received and has been removed. Also, when it was still in use, you were supposed to set it before loading `magit`.

`magit-log-edit-mode-hook` is also obsolete. `magit-log-edit.el` was removed three years ago and support was completely removed two and a half years ago. It's place was taken by `git-commit.el` and the hook to use now is `git-commit-setup-hook`.